# How to loop sas macro by date?

Tags: loops, date, macros, sas

I defined a macro which get data of 1 day.
For example

```
%macro getOneday(stnd_d);
data _null_;
    call symputx('numdate',&stnd_d.);
run;
data oneday&numdate;
   set alldata;
   where stdd = &stnd_d;
run;
%mend;
```

Now I want to loop that macro from start date to end date.

```
 data _null_;
    do i = '01mar2015'd to '30mar2015'd;
    %getOneday(stnd_d = i)
    end;
 run;
```

I don't know how can I pass the date expression value to %getOneday() as a parameter.

Comment: the reason why that loop doesn't work is that, I think, the passed parameter 'i' is just number not date expression.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you understand that macro - `getOneday` would simply write all the code written inside it, to the `data _null_` statement by replacing the `%getOneday` and since you cannot write a `data` step inside a `data` step, its throwing an error. You simply have to replace the `data _NULL_` statement with a `macro` like below.
Also using date like that would not work as `Macro` would treat them as `char`, you will have to convert them into `date` format, before using them in `%do` loop.

```
%macro test;
data _null_;
date1='01mar2015'd;
date2='30mar2015'd;
call symputx("date1",date1);
call symputx("date2",date2);
run;
%put &date1.;
%put &date2.;

    %do i = &date1. %to &date2.;
    %getOneday(stnd_d = &i.)
    %end;

 %mend;

 %test;
```